# namespace commandTrees is not visiable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

```
using System.Data.Common.CommandTrees;
```

It is showing an error as below :

> "Error    3   The type or namespace name 'CommandTrees' does not exist in
>   the namespace 'System.Data.Common' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)   "

in visual studio 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Framework reference to System.Data.Entity.dll